# Fade out animation doesn't stay faded out

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

I have a simple fade out animation function for my android app, it works, but the issue I am having is that, after the fade out animation has run, the view (`TextView` in this case) does not stay faded out, the `alpha` value becomes 1 again.

Here is the `fadeOut` function code:

```
 fun fadeOut(duration: Long = 100) : AlphaAnimation{
        val fadeOut = AlphaAnimation(1f, 0f)
        fadeOut.interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
        fadeOut.duration = duration
        return fadeOut
    }
```

And I use it like this:

```
myTextView.startAnimation(fadeOut(500))
```

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Animation::setFillAfter` function would do the trick for you, the code would be like this:

```
val animation = fadeOut(500)
animation.fillAfter = true

myTextView.startAnimation(animation)
```

Although, this solution only preserves the alpha value of the view after the animation ends, if you want to change the visibility of the view, you need to change it when the animation ends using `Animation.AnimationListener` interface, the code would be like this:

```
myTextView.startAnimation(fadeOut(500).apply {
    setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
        }
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
            myTextView.visibility = View.GONE
        }
        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set visibility in handler after running animation

```
myTextView.startAnimation(fadeOut(500))
Handler().postDelayed({
        myTextView.visibility = View.GONE               
    },500)
```